How flexible are small airplanes wings compared to airliners?
When talking about flexible wings, it always comes to mind big airliners like the 787 or the A350.
But knowing that flexible wings help reduce the flight bumpiness and small airplanes are known for being more bumpy, I wonder how flexible is the wing of a typical modern day GA airplane like the Cirrus SR22 vs a modern day airliner like the 787?

All wings are flexible, if they didn't flex they would break! I'm not entirely clear what the question is here.

Like how flexible are they compared to a 787 wings for example. Updated title.

What are you actually asking here? If you want to know why airliners are less bumpy than light aircraft then the principal factor is the overall mass of the aircraft including payload and fuel. If you actually do want to compare the structural stiffness of the airframes then I suppose one could come up with something that expresses displacement per unit force (like a Young's modulus, if you will), but I doubt that would tell you very much given the vastly different sizes of the airframes involved.

They all flex to some degree where some or all of a wing is cantilevered from the fuselage, or outboard of a strut, anywhere there is a beam in bending supported at one end.
Cruise along in a fabric aircraft with wood spars, like a Citabria, in bumpy air and you can see the outer part of the wing beyond the strut flexing up and down enough to be obvious (maybe up to an inch at the tip if the G load is high enough). It's not enough to affect ride quality noticeably though.
On a glider or motorglider with cantilevered wings with long spans, they flop around quite a lot (maybe 6 inches to a foot at the tip). On sailplanes with very long spans and low wing loadings, the flex makes the ride much more pleasant at high speeds compared to a glider with very stiff spars.
So, wing flex does enhance the ride in bumpy air in gliders and motorgliders, and possibly somewhat on the latest composite airplanes, but generally not enough to notice on most light aircraft.

A very important consideration to your question is the mass of the fuselage.
Modern airliner wings may be way less flexible on a foot per foot basis than light aircraft wings, but they are longer.

However, there is a much greater resistance to movement (inertia) with a heavier fuselage.

As a result, when a gust hits the aircraft, smaller aircraft will tend to move (as a whole) rather than bend their wings.  With larger aircraft, it's the opposite.
Another consideration is the smaller surface area to mass ratio of larger aircraft.  A ride on a paper airplane will certainly be bumpier than a 747 in gusty winds.
To summarize, in response to a gust, the resistance to  bending torque
on the airliner wing may be within a degree of magnitude to a GA aircraft, but the aircraft mass differential is on the order of 2 degrees.  The airliner is easily 100x heavier than the GA aircraft.
Just like riding in a big Cadillac vs a go-kart, the bumps in the road are felt way less in the Cadillac, even though the suspension may be slightly stiffer.

don't you mean the opposite on your second paragraph?

Second paragraph edited.
